# Missing mysql2 gem Amazon Web Services EC2 error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, rubygems

When I try to open my site it gives me this error.

!!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2'

I have added it to my Gemfile, but still no avail.
And changed all my adapters to mysql2 in the database.yml

Running 
Rails 3.0.7
Ruby 1.8.7 enterprise

Comment: how about changing all refs to just  mysql  does that help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my database say it was called dog but it displayed as Dog so I had to configure database.yml to change it to dog. – Andy 0 secs ago edit

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting this error because the latest mysql2 gem doesn't contain the ActiveRecord adaptor (they've excluded it because Rails 3.1 has it built into ActiveRecord).

You should require the old version of mysql2 in your gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2', "~> 0.2.7"
```

This is as per instructions in [mysql2 README doc](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2)

Comment: I have tried that and yet it still gives me the same error. :/

Comment: Did you `bundle install` after changing the gemfile?

Comment: Hi Rob, Yes I did. It still does not work. Bundle install installs though.

Comment: Righteo.  Sorry I couldn't help!  BTW, have you tried adding the 'mysql' gem to your gemfile, too?  I had to add both in order to get the mysql2 gem working.